# If $f$ function then $f^{-1}$ function iff $f$ function injective (one-to-one).

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

During the lecture we learned this phrase:

> "If $f$ is a function then $f^{-1}$ is a function iff $f$ is injective (one-to-one)."

But why? 
What with onto? $f$ doesn't need to be Surjective (onto)?

For example:
$$f:A \rightarrow B$$
$$A=\{1,2,3\} $$
$$B=\{1,2,3,4\} $$
$$f=\{(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)\}$$

$f$ is an injective function but $ f^{-1} $ can't be a function because for 4 we can`t find a place to go.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is supposed to be defined on the direct image of $f$, not on the whole codomain $B$

Comment: I would say your observation is technically correct. Functions are invertible iff they're bijective.

Comment: I'm not sure how others handle this, but I was always taught that $f$ has a true inverse iff it's bijective. We can construct $g: B\to A$ such that $g=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1)\}$, so $g$ acts like an inverse to $f$, but it's not a real inverse, because $g(4)$ exists, and $f^{-1}(4)$ is undefined.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 The claim doesn't say anything about invertibility. It simply says $f^{-1}$ is a function. I would be curious to know how the lecturer defined $f^{-1}$.

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ is an injective function and $C\subseteq B$ is its image then there is a function $g:C\to A$ that serves as inverse of the function $A\to C$ that is prescribed by $a\mapsto f(a)$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, but notice how $f$ is defined as a set of ordered pairs. If the instructor defined the inverse as the reversal of ordered pairs then it is implied that the inverse has domain $Im f$ and not $B$. In that case the notion that $f$ must be bijective is false.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, I see your point, thanks

Comment: I understand, thanks you! So why to choose the name $f^{-1}$ and not $g$ or something less confusing? What is the idea actually of that $f^{-1}$?

Comment: You should add the **formal definitions** of "function" and of $f^{-1}$ given in your lecture.  Otherwise it will be difficult to write an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this context a function $f$ is actually a set of ordered pairs having the special property that for every $a\in\{x\mid\exists y\langle x,y\rangle\in f\}$  (its **domain**) there is a unique $b$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$.

The function is injective if moreover for every $b\in\{y\mid\exists x\langle x,y\rangle\in f\}$ (its **range** or **image**) there is a unique $a$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in f$.

Defining $f^{-1}:=\{\langle y,x\rangle\mid \langle x,y\rangle\in f\}$ we can reformulate this by the statement that $f^{-1}$ is a function.

In your example $f^{-1}=f$.

---

**edit**:

Notation $f:A\to B$ suggests that $A$ is the domain of the function and that the range of $f$ is a subset of $B$ (its **codomain**). Then injectivity of $f$ does not guarantee the existence of an inverse $f^{-1}:B\to A$ as you noticed correctly. However it does guarantee the existence of an inverse $f^{-1}:R\to A$ where $R\subseteq B$ denotes the range of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely right: A function $f:\>A\to B$ has an inverse $f^{-1}:\>B\to A$ iff $f$ is bijective.

But mathematicians are sometimes sloppy: If $f:\>A\to B$ is injective you can define an "inverse"
$$g:\quad f(A)\to A,\qquad y\mapsto{\rm the}\bigl(f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigr)$$
without specifying supplementary data or making any choices.

If $f$ is not injective, but an "important" function, so that an inverse is extremely desirable, you can enforce a "restricted" inverse by restricting $f$ to a suitable chosen subset $A'\subset A$, on which $f$ is injective. Such is the case, e.g.,  for $f:=\sin$, whereby the latter is defined on all of ${\mathbb R}$, and is injective on the interval $\bigl[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\bigr]$. The inverse of the restriction $\sin\restriction\bigl[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\bigr]$ is then called $\arcsin$, and is a map $[{-1},1]\to\bigl[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\bigr]$.

Comment: The question is tagged with elementary-set-theory. On that area functions are identified with their graphs. I think the OP had a lecture in settheory when the phrase was posed.

Answer (score 0):

We define $f^{-1}=\{(x,y): (y,x)\in f\}$ Then $f^{-1}$ is a relation with domain equal to the image of $f$ and codomain equal to $A$.

Suppose $f$ is injective. To show $f^{-1}$ is a function we must show that if $(x,y)\in f^{-1}$ and $(x,z)\in f^{-1}$ then $y=z$. But if $(x,y)\in f^{-1}$ then $(y,x)\in f$ and likewise, $(z,x)\in f$. This means that $f(y)=f(z)=x$ and since $f$ is injective, $y=z$, therefore $f^{-1}$ is a function.

Conversely, suppose $f^{-1}$ is a function and $f(x)=f(y)=z$. Then $(z,y), (z,x)\in f^{-1}$ and since $f^{-1}$ is a function, $y=x$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.